# Default value in cascading dropdown list in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, cascadingdropdown

I have a cascading dropdown list. Functionality is working fine. But I want this dropdown should be selected with a value coming from database by default.   Lets say in this dropdown bank name icici should be selected by default as vank name  icici is coming from database,  dropdown should have the value same, which is coming frim database, and then I will be able to select the value of my choice from the list of items in this dropdown.

```
[WebMethod]
public CascadingDropDownNameValue[] GetBankList(
string knownCategoryValues,
string category)
{

List<CascadingDropDownNameValue> values =
new List<CascadingDropDownNameValue>();

values.Add(new CascadingDropDownNameValue(
"ICICI", 1001.ToString()));

values.Add(new CascadingDropDownNameValue(
"AXIS", 1002.ToString()));

values.Add(new CascadingDropDownNameValue(
"AMEX", 1003.ToString()));

values.Add(new CascadingDropDownNameValue(
"HDFC", 1004.ToString()));

values.Add(new CascadingDropDownNameValue(
"OPUS", 1005.ToString()));

values.Add(new CascadingDropDownNameValue(
"HSBC", 1006.ToString()));

values.Add(new CascadingDropDownNameValue(
"SBI", 1007.ToString()));

values.Add(new CascadingDropDownNameValue(
"ICICI-SHAKTI", 1008.ToString()));

values.Add(new CascadingDropDownNameValue(
"CITI", 1009.ToString()));

values.Add(new CascadingDropDownNameValue(
"CORP", 1010.ToString()));

values.Add(new CascadingDropDownNameValue(
"HDFC-PRIZM", 1011.ToString()));

values.Add(new CascadingDropDownNameValue(
"CUB", 1012.ToString()));

values.Add(new CascadingDropDownNameValue(
"AXISB24", 1013.ToString()));

values.Add(new CascadingDropDownNameValue(
"IDBI", 1014.ToString()));

values.Add(new CascadingDropDownNameValue(
"LVB", 1015.ToString()));

values.Add(new CascadingDropDownNameValue(
"MASHREQ", 1016.ToString()));

values.Add(new CascadingDropDownNameValue(
"YES", 1017.ToString()));

values.Add(new CascadingDropDownNameValue(
"FEDERAL", 1018.ToString()));

values.Add(new CascadingDropDownNameValue(
"SBI87", 1019.ToString()));

return values.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set your `cascadicascading1.selectedvalue="ICICI"`
on your `cascading controle`

Answer (score 0):

If, for some reason, you can't get the Selected Value on the front end but you need t retrieve it in the call itself You  can use the `**ContextKey**` Property on you call method definition:
Your method cascading drop down would look something like this:

```
<cc1:CascadingDropDown ID="ccdYourCascadingDropDownControl" 
runat="server" 
TargetControlID="ddControl"
ParentControlID="ddlParent" 
Category="yourCategory"
ServicePath="YourASMX.asmx"
ServiceMethod="GetBankList"
EnableViewState="true"
LoadingText="Retrieving"
UseContextKey="true"
ContextKey="selectedValContext"
EmptyText="N/A"     
>
```

Where
Your Web Method would like something like this:
you'll have to write a method *CheckifSelected* which returns a bool which compares your List Value to the desired selected value.

```
[WebMethod]
public CascadingDropDownNameValue[] GetBankList(
string knownCategoryValues,
string category,
string contextKey

)
{
  selectedVal = LocateSelectedVal(contextKey)
List<CascadingDropDownNameValue> values =
new List<CascadingDropDownNameValue>();

values.Add(new CascadingDropDownNameValue(
"ICICI", 1001.ToString(), CheckifSelected()));

values.Add(new CascadingDropDownNameValue(
"AXIS", 1002.ToString(), CheckifSelected()));

values.Add(new CascadingDropDownNameValue(
"AMEX", 1003.ToString(), CheckifSelected()));

values.Add(new CascadingDropDownNameValue(
"HDFC", 1004.ToString(),  CheckifSelected()));

values.Add(new CascadingDropDownNameValue(
"OPUS", 1005.ToString(), CheckifSelected()));

values.Add(new CascadingDropDownNameValue(
"HSBC", 1006.ToString(), CheckifSelected()));

values.Add(new CascadingDropDownNameValue(
"SBI", 1007.ToString(), CheckifSelected()));

values.Add(new CascadingDropDownNameValue(
"ICICI-SHAKTI", 1008.ToString(), CheckifSelected()));

values.Add(new CascadingDropDownNameValue(
"CITI", 1009.ToString(), CheckifSelected()));

values.Add(new CascadingDropDownNameValue(
"CORP", 1010.ToString(), CheckifSelected()));

values.Add(new CascadingDropDownNameValue(
"HDFC-PRIZM", 1011.ToString(), CheckifSelected()));

values.Add(new CascadingDropDownNameValue(
"CUB", 1012.ToString(), CheckifSelected()));

values.Add(new CascadingDropDownNameValue(
"AXISB24", 1013.ToString(), CheckifSelected()));

values.Add(new CascadingDropDownNameValue(
"IDBI", 1014.ToString(), CheckifSelected()));

values.Add(new CascadingDropDownNameValue(
"LVB", 1015.ToString(), CheckifSelected()));

values.Add(new CascadingDropDownNameValue(
"MASHREQ", 1016.ToString(), CheckifSelected()));

values.Add(new CascadingDropDownNameValue(
"YES", 1017.ToString(), CheckifSelected()));

values.Add(new CascadingDropDownNameValue(
"FEDERAL", 1018.ToString(), CheckifSelected()));

values.Add(new CascadingDropDownNameValue(
"SBI87", 1019.ToString(), CheckifSelected()));

return values.ToArray();
```